# Can't reinitialise plugin after destroy method called

Tags: javascript, methods, jquery-plugins, coffeescript

After a previous question ([Can't destroy jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24977621/cant-destroy-jquery-plugin/)) I have finally got the destroy method working well, but the issue is now that I can't initialise the plugin again.

I can call the plugin by `$('#element').fullscreen()` and destroy it with `$('#element').fullscreen('destroy')` but then when I call `$('#element').fullscreen()` it simply returns the element and doesn't initialise.

```
(($, window) ->

  'use strict'

  # Create the defaults once
  pluginName = 'fullscreen'
  dataKey    = 'plugin_#{pluginName}'
  defaults =
    reference: window
    offset: 0
    debug: false

  class Plugin
    constructor: ( @element, options ) ->
      @options = $.extend { }, defaults, options
      @init()

    init: ->
      @bind()
      @setHeight()

    bind: ->
      # Trigger on resize

      $(window).on 'debouncedresize', =>
        @log 'Resize event fired'
        @setHeight()

      $(window).on 'orientationchange', =>
        @log 'Orientation changed'
        @setHeight()

      # When scrolling on a touchscreen
      # prevent further resizes due to address bar shrinking
      $(window).on 'touchstart', =>
        @log 'Touch start fired'
        @unbind()

    # Getter
    getHeight: ->
      @log 'Get height from: ', @options.reference
      $( @options.reference ).height()

    # Setter
    setHeight: ->
      # Make sure the offset is a number
      if @options.offset == parseInt( @options.offset )
        offset = @options.offset
      else
        offset = 0

      $( @element ).css
        'min-height' : @getHeight() - offset

      @callback()

    unbind: ->
      @log 'Unbind the debouncedresize, touchstart and orientationchange event handlers'
      $(window).off 'debouncedresize touchstart orientationchange'

    destroy: ->
      @unbind()

      @log 'Remove min-height from: ', @element
      $( @element ).removeAttr 'style'

      return

    callback: ->
      @log 'Callback fired'

      # Check if the callback is a function
      if typeof @options.callback == 'function'
        # Execute the callback and return the origin element as `this`
        @options.callback.call( @element )

    log: ( msg, object ) ->
      if @options.debug
        if !object
          object = ''
        console.log( pluginName + ': ' + msg, object )

  # The plugin itself
  $.fn[pluginName] = ( args... ) ->
    @each ->
      plugin = $.data(@, dataKey)

      # Allow .fullscreen('destroy')
      if typeof args[0] == 'string'
        plugin?[args[0]]?()
      else if !plugin
        $.data(@, dataKey, new Plugin(@, args[0]))

  return $.fn[pluginName]

) jQuery, window
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [`$.removeData`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.removeData/) to get rid of the `dataKey` data so that `$.data(@, dataKey)` will return `undefined` again. If you don't manually remove the `dataKey` then `$.data(@, dataKey)` will keep returning your plugin instance and the `else if !plugin` will fail.

Something like this should be sufficient:

```
destroy: ->
  @unbind()

  @log 'Remove min-height from: ', @element
  $( @element ).removeAttr 'style'

  $.removeData(@element, dataKey) # <------------ Add this

  return
```

Updated quick'n'dirty demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/568SU/2/

Sorry, I probably should have thought of this last time.

Comment: Awesome. Of all the internet, someone else in Whistler helps me. I owe you a beer.

Comment: @Craig: That's hilarious. I'm partial to Black Tusk Ale these days :)